# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку циклически менялся текст в TextView?

Tags: java, android, button, textview

Дано: 1 TextView, 3 строковых ресурса. 
Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку циклически менялся текст в TextView?
Т.е. по умолчанию отображается текст 1, нажал на кнопку - отображается текст 2, нажал еще раз - текст 3, еще раз - снова текст 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

1) Объявить глобальную переменную, инициализировать нулём `int mCurValue = 0;`

2) Объявить массив текстовый `String[] mTexts;`

3) в `onClickListener`'е из массива берём текст по иднексу `mTexts[mCurValue]`. После этого наращиваем `mCurValue`:

```
mCurValue++;
if(mCurValue >= mTexts.length) 
   mCurValue = 0 ;
```

Решение получше - не глобальную переменную объявлять, а задавать текущий индекс в `tag` элемента: `mTextView.setTag()`, а получать из `mTextView.getTag()`. Инициализировать нулём.

Comment: Спасибо !  Первый вариант подходит.

Answer (score 1):

1. Найти `TextView` в разметке.
2. Там же найти кнопку.
3. На кнопку повесить слушатель нажатий.
4. Завести массив из строковых ресурсов.
5. Завести `int` переменную-счётчик, показывающую какой элемент массива сейчас отображается. По умолчанию равно нулю.
6. Завести `int` переменную со значением равным длине массива.
7. В слушателе из п.3. проверять меньше ли `int` из п.5 `int` из п.6. Если да,  и при этом не равна `int` из п.6 минус 1, то `int` из п.5 увеливаем на единицу. Если нет, то приравниваем `int` из п.5 нулю.
8. Далее в слушателе присваиваем `TextView` текст из массива, беря вычисленный нами элемент из п.7.

Comment: И Вам спасибо !